# Python code to search and display title of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a code which can read today's date from excel and subsequently find the day and the values (11 or 12) in the same row. Example when I find "12" on Monday (16-03-2020) I want it to display XYZ & RST (Column names).

Is it possible to do so. Please help me out.

[image: Excel image attached]

Comment: Take a look at [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using pandas dataframe, this might get what you want

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
df = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx', parse_dates=True)
df['Date ']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date ']) 

>>df

Date    Day ABC XYZ PQR RST
0   2020-03-17  Tuesday 11  11  12  12
1   2020-03-12  Saturday    12  11  11  12
2   2020-03-18  Wednesday   12  12  11  11

today= date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
df_slice = df[df["Date "]==today]

>>df_slice
Date    Day ABC XYZ PQR RST
0   2020-03-17  Tuesday 11  11  12  12



my_cols = list(df_slice.columns)

del my_cols[0:2] # delete columns name not be searched

for col in my_cols:
    df_slice[col] = df_slice[col].apply(str) # apply str to check match case
    if df_slice[col].str.contains("11").any() == True:
        print(col)
>>PQR
>>RST
```

Comment: Hi, Manish thanks for the help. But what I want to display is, if number "12" is found in the row then column name must be displayed. say in print() or any where. Taking your output, say 12 is displayed under column names POR & RST , then I want PQR & RST to be displayed in print() statement.

Comment: there you go @SumantKashyap there might be Warning for dataframe slice but can be ignore as we are not actually modifying any data